# sql server parameter size overloading

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am calling a stored procedure from my ASP.NET application. the stored procedure takes one parameter. the value that i am providing from my WEB Form is too large that it did not fully loading in variable of sql server. the data type of my sql server parameter is nvarchar(max) and the data type in my ASP.NET application is string. 
the stored procedure is as below

```
Create procedure p_getProducts
@nm_emp nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN

  select * from tblProduct where nm_user in(convert(nvarchar(max),@nm_emp));

END
```

please tell me which sql server data type i should use to overcome this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: why are you converting the variable into the same data type?

Comment: You have a logic problem here. A parameter passed in this way cannot expand itself to a list of IN values. Your query will never work. (at least not if @nm_emp is something like 'joe','mark','steve' )

Comment: @steve, yes i am formating the values in c# like 'joe','mark','steve' and save it in variable and pass it to the stored procedure. they are working well but when the size of text in parameter increased then it creates problem

Comment: @jw i have tried it by eliminating conversion but still the problem occures.

Comment: Are you sure? Have you tried with more that one name and the results include both names?

Comment: yep its working i have tried it

Comment: @Candy You are mistaken. This definitely doesn't work.

Comment: @Candy: that will not work, so either that's not your code or you have a row with that value in it.  See this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0804b/3

Answer (score 1):

For what I could suppose from your code, you should work with [dynamic-sql](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-dynamic-sql-in-stored-procedures) and not using directly the parameter as value for the IN clause. Try with this proc.

```
Create procedure p_getProducts
      @nm_emp nvarchar(max)
AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX); 
    SELECT @SQL = N'select * from tblProduct where nm_user in(' + 
                  @nm_emp + N')'

    EXEC sp_executeSQL @SQL
```

Comment: As long as his parameter doesn't exceed about 3960 unicode chars. :)

Comment: Possible SQL injection issue depending on where the value in `@nm_emp` comes from.

Comment: @MartinSmith if he calls this function from ASP.NET using procedure ADO function and a good sanitizer he can manage to make safe calls imho.

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't possible to but for all we know it just takes the values directly from `Request.Form["MultiSelectListbox"]`